# SQL Server 2008R2 Express and LocalDB on same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to evaluate LocalDB. My computer already has SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on it (in addition to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and SQL Server 2008 Standard).

When I try to install LocalDB, it asks for confirmation to upgrade. So it is trying to upgrade by 2008 R2 Express to Localdb? And I hit no and didn't proceed further.

Can someone please point me to links where they explain what exactly happens? Will my 2008 R2 Express be gone forever? All databases will be upgraded to LocalDB? There will not be a Express service anymore?

I just want to use localdb as an addition, not as a replacement. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to install LocalDB? If you do it via SSDT (SQL Server Development Tools), it won't touch any of your other instances of SQL Server. Also, remember that LocalDB is not an instance of SQL Server in the sense that your other instances are. It's essentially a process that spins up when needed (an attempt is made to connect to it) and shuts down when not needed. Therefore, it's not competing with your other SQL Server instances.

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit msi from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062
It is somehow modifying existing env/databases. Apparently if I have 2008R2 express db and I attach it to Local db, it no longer can be used by R2. I am missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is trying to do or why. But, I would bypass this and just install SSDT (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) which will also install LocalDB and not touch your other instances of SQL Server.

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time. I realised I have already installed it at some time in the past and so it's trying to reinstall/upgrade.

Comment: Ah, good. Enjoy LocalDB. It's an interesting approach by Microsoft.